# Commuting filtered colimits & finite limits in infinitary theories

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads, algebraic-theory

Filtered colimits & finite limits commute in categories that are finitary monadic over Set (i.e. algebras of finitary algebraic theories). Results such as Fred Linton's result that if categories of algebras over Set have reflexive coequalisers, then they're cocomplete, suggest that lots of other categories of algebras will also have filtered colimits.

My question is whether there are any known such categories (monadic over Set) where filtered colimits & finite limits commute, which aren't finitary algebraic. And whether you can classify such theories?

Comment: [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57099/why-do-filtered-colimits-commute-with-finite-limits) is relevant and possibly answers your question.

Comment: I don't think it does. Their answer lists some examples in which it holds but doesn't classify them, or give any examples monadic over set which aren't finitary algebraic

Comment: I think there are no examples that are toposes. Have you thought about Banach spaces with contractions or compact Hausdorff spaces? I think kernels don't commute with countable unions in Ban but I haven't tried to think about CHaus.

Answer (score 2):

The category $sSet$ of simplicial sets fits the bill.

As $sSet$ is a topos, it is Barr-exact. Moreover, the coproduct of representables $D = \amalg_{n \in \mathbb N} \Delta^n$ is a projective generator. Hence $Hom(D,-) : sSet \to Set$ is monadic, as mentioned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193689/colimit-density-and-monads/193796#193796).

As $sSet$ is a topos, we moreover have that finite limits commute with filtered colimits.

Finally, $sSet$ is not finitary monadic over $Set$. If it were, then the forgetful functor $sSet \to Set$ would be representable by a compact generator. But no compact object of $sSet$ is a generator.

---

With prodding from the comments, here is a more general statement. Let $\mathcal C$ be a small category, and let $C = \amalg_{c \in \mathcal C} y(c)$ be the coproduct of all representable presheaves on $\mathcal C$. Note that as a coproduct of representables (which are always projective), $C$ is projective.

**Observation 1:**  Assume that $\mathcal C$ is strongly connected (for every $c, d \in \mathcal C$ we have $\mathcal C(c,d) \neq \emptyset$). Then $C$ is a generator in $\mathcal C$.

**Proof:** Let $f \neq g: X \rightrightarrows Y$ be an epimorphism in $Psh(\mathcal C)$. Then there is $c \in \mathcal C$ such that $f_c \neq g_c$, so there is $x \in X(c)$ such that $f_c(x) \neq g_c(x)$. Letting $h_d : d \to c$ be a morphism, we let $k: C \to X$ be given by $k \iota_d = x \circ y(h_d)$ where $\iota_d : y(d) \to C$ is the coproduct inclusion for $d \in \mathcal C$. Then $f k \neq g k$.

**Observation 2:** Assume that $\mathcal C$ is not strongly connected. Then $C$ is not a generator in $Psh(\mathcal C)$.

**Proof:** Let $c,d \in \mathcal C$ be such that $\mathcal C(c,d) = \emptyset$. Let $j_0, j_1 : y(d) \rightrightarrows y(d) \amalg y(d)$ be the coproduct inclusions. Then $j_0 \neq j_1$. But there are no morphisms $C \to y(d)$, because by composition with $\iota_c$ we would get a morphism $c \to d$. Thus $C$ does not see the difference between $j_0$ and $j_1$, so $C$ is not a generator.

**Corollary 3:** $C$ is a generator in $Psh(\mathcal C)$ if and only if $\mathcal C$ is strongly connected.

**Corollary 4:** In $Psh(\mathcal C)$, finite limits commute with filtered colimits. Supposing that $\mathcal C$ is strongly connected, we have that $\mathcal C(C,-) : Psh(\mathcal C) \to Set$ is monadic. If $\mathcal C$ has infinitely many objects, then this functor is not finitary monadic.

Comment: How general is it? I mean, does it work for other presheaf categories?

Comment: @Z.M Let $\mathcal C$ be a small category, and let's think about when the coproduct of representables $C = \amalg_{c \in \mathcal C} c$ is a projective generator. It is always projective. It is a generator if, for every presheaf $X$ and every $c \in \mathcal C$, there exists a morphism $c \to X$. For this it is necessary and sufficient that $\mathcal C$ be _strongly  connected_ in the sense that every object of $\mathcal C$ admits a morphism to every other object of $\mathcal C$. So if $\mathcal C$ is strongly connected, then $Psh(\mathcal C)$ is monadic over $Set$.

Comment: I don’t think that reasoning is quite correct (consider the empty presheaf!) but strong connectedness probably does have something to do with it.

Comment: I feel like there can be topoi where filtered colimits and finite limits don't commute. Of course $sSet$ is not one of them, but just to indicate that the justification for why this works in $sSet$ is probably more because it's a presheaf category, than because it's a topos :)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi In fact, finite limits and filtered colimits commute in any Grothendieck topos. Here's the proof described [on the nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutativity+of+limits+and+colimits#examples). Clearly this is true for presheaf toposes. Now let $I$ be filtered and $L : Psh(C) \to E$ be a left exact localization. Then the colimit functor $\varinjlim^E : Fun(I, E) \to E$ factors as $Fun(I,E) \xrightarrow{inc} Fun(I, Psh(C)) \xrightarrow \varinjlim Psh(C) \xrightarrow L E$, and all three functors preserve finite limits, so $\varinjlim^E$ preserves finite limits as desired.

Comment: @ZhenLin Ah, sure. But the empty presheaf is the only exception, and the conclusion is still correct. See the edit.

Comment: @Tim : ah of course, my bad !